# Why are the multiple points generated for each vertex? How do I get one point per selected vertex?

Tags: geometry-nodes, vertex-groups, instances

I'm trying to place instances on specific vertices of an object. I have the object I want to instance, and I created a vertex group of the vertices where I want to place them.

When I put everything together, however, I get nine instances on each vertex instead of one per vertex. If I look at the points Blender generates from the vertex group, I see that there are nine points per vertex. Why is this happening? How do I get one point per vertex?

Thank you!

[image: Node setup]

[image: Nine points per selected vertex]

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out:

I had the geometry nodes modifier after a subsurf modifier in the modifier stack. Switched the order and everything works as expected.